# hover effect doesn't work

Tags: jquery, hover, hide, show

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop != 0)
            $('#header').hide();
        else    
            $('#header').show();
    });
    $('#header').hover(
        function (e) {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scrollTop != 0) {
                $('#header').show();
            }
        },
        function (e) {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scrollTop != 0) {
                $('#header').hide();
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Depend on scrolling, it works well.
But with mouseover, it's not working especially in IE7. :(

Is it wrong?

Comment: @DerekHenderson  lol!  at OP use instead mouseenter/mouseleave and see if it works

Comment: Can u find someone using IE 7 !!! Jquery 2  does not Support IE 8 and earliers :D , this is not your problem . :D :D :D

Comment: You collected 17 (!) questions and accepted none. People will stop answer your questions. Take care to fix that. It's a way to say "thanks" here on Stack Overflow, and for future visitors it's a helpful information to see which one was accepted by you as a correct answer that helped resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Once you **hide** your fixed HEADER, (supposing you're doing it right: `fixed`)
there's no way you can recall the `mouseenter` on that element cause it's not stack any more in it's original space.

You better handle the element's opacity. Here's an example using jQuery's `.fadeTo()`

http://jsbin.com/eviziq/3/edit

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#header').stop().fadeTo(300, $(window).scrollTop() > 0 ? 0.1 : 1 );
});

$('#header').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > 0 ) {
        $('#header').stop().fadeTo(300, e.type=="mouseenter" ? 1 : 0.1 );
    }
});
```

<sub>I used Opacity `0.1` instead of `0` just for demo purpose.</sub>